# Linking Paypal with Rails App - return URL not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

In my project I'm using Paypal for making customers to pay. I have followed the railscast given below

[Paypal API Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics)

Everything is working fine. but after the customer payment is done, paypal doesnot showing 'return to app' button. Is there anyway to make appear this?

Can anyone help me to get rid from this issue?

Comment: It might not be a full button like that video shows, but you should see a link or something that says return to merchant.  Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing once the payment is completed?

Comment: You could also consider enabling Auto-Return within your PayPal profile.